# How can you view the contents of another player's enderchest? [1.14]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I think you can use

```
/execute as <selector> run replaceitem entity @s enderchest.0 minecraft:stone
```

to change the contents of someone's enderchest, but that doesn't really show you the contents of their ender chest.

I also think that you can use /data modify to copy the contents of someone's ender chest into a normal chest where you can view it there, but I'm not too familiar with /data modify. I tried something like:

```
/data modify block 73 4 53 Items[] set from block 74 4 53
```

That didn't really work, it just cleared the items from the chest, one by one. I'm assuming that this is because the ender chest is stored in the player data, and that the actual chest is "empty?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second command doesn't work because the ender chest as a block doesn't store the ender chest items of individual players. Whose items would you expect to get with that command? The command doesn't know.

The ender chest items are stored in a player's `EnderItems` tag, so you get them for example with this command:

```
/data get entity @p EnderItems
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command:

```
/data modify block (coords for chest) Items set from entity (playerName) EnderItems
```

And it will copy the items into the chest at the coordinates.